# vs2015 Error when right clicking project in solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp

I am having issues with creating UWP apps. If i right click my project in solution's explorer I get the following error pop up in VS2015

`An exception has been occurred while getting the visual studio framework version of the project.`

Pressing ok brings the error window back again. This happens about 5 times and then the menu that is expected appears.

Any ideas why?

Things I have tried.

- Recreate the project.
- Repair VS 2015 installation
- Move the project on to my laptop. Laptop
  is running VS2017 RC and latest insider preview of windows 10.

Update 1:
Tried what ezaspi mentions in the first comment and all the errors from the log are as below.

```
<entry>
<record>523</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:52.502</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Extension Manager</source>
<description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.WindowsStore&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\10\WINDOWS STORE SDK\...</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.0\METRO SDK\</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>524</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:52.502</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Extension Manager</source>
<description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.Desktop&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\10\DESKTOP SDK\...</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.1\DESKTOP SDK\</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>525</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:52.502</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Extension Manager</source>
<description>Extension will not be loaded because an extension with the same ID &apos;Microsoft.Windows.DevelopmentKit.WindowsStore&apos; is already loaded at C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\10\WINDOWS STORE SDK\...</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\MICROSOFT\EXTENSIONMANAGER\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS KITS\8.1\WINDOWS STORE SDK\</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>166</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:50.340</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
<description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.Navigation.dll&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\R0KXUUR5.OBE\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer.Navigation.dll</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>167</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:50.344</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
<description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.dll&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\R0KXUUR5.OBE\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.dll</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>168</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:50.349</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
<description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.TeamFoundation.CodeReview.Controls.dll&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\R0KXUUR5.OBE\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.CodeReview.Controls.dll</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>169</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:50.381</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
<description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.TeamFoundation.CodeReview.Components.dll&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\R0KXUUR5.OBE\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.CodeReview.Components.dll</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>170</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:50.386</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
<description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.dll&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\R0KXUUR5.OBE\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Provider.dll</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>171</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:50.390</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
<description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Controls.dll&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\R0KXUUR5.OBE\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Controls.dll</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>172</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:50.394</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
<description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Build.dll&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\R0KXUUR5.OBE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.Build.dll</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>173</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:50.398</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
<description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.dll&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\R0KXUUR5.OBE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.dll</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>174</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:50.402</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
<description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.ContextManagement.Package.dll&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\R0KXUUR5.OBE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ContextManagement.Package.dll</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>175</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:50.407</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
<description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.dll&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\R0KXUUR5.OBE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.dll</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>176</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:50.411</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
<description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\R0KXUUR5.OBE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>177</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:50.416</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
<description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.dll&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\R0KXUUR5.OBE\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Controls.dll</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>178</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:50.420</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
<description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspaces.Contracts, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\0UHH1GTS.5EQ\TMLanguage.dll</path>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>179</record>
<time>2016/11/30 16:56:50.425</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.ExtensibilityHosting.VsShellComponentModelHost</source>
<description>Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.SharePointReporting.dll&apos; or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.</description>
<path>C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\R0KXUUR5.OBE\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.SharePointReporting.dll</path>
```

`

Comment: Have you tried checking the logs during startup? See example
http://blog.masterdevs.com/debugging-a-visual-studio-crash/

Comment: Tried what you said and added above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am having the same issue. You wouldn't happen to be using SyncFusion controls would you? After troubleshooting my issue and doing some of the same things as you (repairing .Net, SDK, Visual Studio) I then thought about the error a bit more. While it is cryptic (and has poor english "An Exception has been occured") these are all clues that it could be any of the frameworks that you have installed via extensions as well.

I also had another clue, the issue started happening a few weeks ago, around the time I updated my SyncFusion controls to the latest version.

So, I went to Tools > Extensions and Updates. I went to Installed > All and found all of the SyncFusion items (there are several) and disabled them all. After you disable them, you have to restart Visual Studio. After that, problem went away!!!

This is a workaround for now. In the meantime, I put in a support ticket with SyncFusion on the issue. I will certainly update this thread when I get a response from them. Also in the meantime, I could try to enable each one, one at a time, to see which one exactly is causing the issue though it could be several of them.

If you are not using SyncFusion, I suggest doing something similar by going through your extensions and disable any that you added on, starting with the most recent add ons, especially if they were added around the same time you started having the problem until you find the culprit.

Hope this helps!

EDIT -By process of elimination (or better, enabling each control again one at a time) I have found that only one of the SyncFusion controls is the culprit in my case. It is the Web Conversion and Migration. All others except this one are enabled and the issue is not happening. Good news if you don't need this control, it might be fine to just leave it disabled. However, I will also update SyncFusion.

EDIT 2 - I recevied a response from Syncfusion. They confirmed and fixed the issue. So, if you dont need that control, leave it disabled. If you do need it, here is the fix.

Updated on 12/2/2016 1:15:55 AM by: Kanimozhi Pandian [Syncfusion]

Hi Michael,

Sorry for the inconvenience caused .

The issue occurred while detecting the framework version of the projects which are not supported by Syncfusion Web conversion and Migration Extension. Now, we have fixed the issue and you can get the updated Syncfusion Web Conversion and Migration extension from here:

```
  http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/168382/ze/Project_Conversion-2034375715
```

Perform the below steps to reinstall the updated Syncfusion Web Conversion and Migration extension.

1. Extract the downloaded zip file.
2. Remove the existing Project Conversion directory from the below location.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Syncfusion\Essential Studio\14.4.0.15\Utilities\Extensions

3. Now, copy the extracted Project Conversion directory to the above mentioned location. Then, perform the steps from the below Knowledge Base to install the updated Syncfusion Web Conversion and Migration  extension to your Visual Studio.

   ```
            https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/4799/how-to-install-the-syncfusion-vsix-packages-manually
   ```

Note: This issue has been fixed and will be included with our Syncfusion 2016 Volume 4 SP1 release.

Regards,
Kanimozhi K.P.

Comment: Yes I am using Syncfusion controls!! I will check the Web Conversion control and try what you say tonight.

Comment: @Gaz83 Great news, it should fix your problem then!!! Also, I just updated my answer, see edit 2, I got a response and fix from Syncfusion. Please make sure to mark as answer if this works for you.

Comment: Yes, Syncfusion for me too. I tried updating to the 2016 Volume 4 SP 1 which appears to show as version 14.4.0.20 in control panel, the three Syncfusion Extensions were / are version 14.4.0.15 with an install date of 1/6/2017 as shown in VS. I installed the SP1 today the 9th. I thought the install date on the extensions would have been updated. Disabling the 3 Syncfusion extensions solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We suspect that the issue might occurred as Visual Studio was opened at the time Syncfusion installation. Please make sure that Visual Studio instance was not open at the time of Syncfusion installation. In order to install the latest Syncfusion extensions to your Visual Studio instead of disabling the Syncfusion extensions, please follow the steps suggested in the following documentation link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/4799/how-to-install-the-syncfusion-vsix-packages-manually

Regards,
Manivannan S.