# Visual Studio error when I right click UWP project not finding framework

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, uwp, win-universal-app

I am having the exact same issue/error as this post from yesterday. [Similar SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827992/vs2015-error-when-right-clicking-project-in-solution-explorer)

SIDE NOTE...As you can see, I am new and therefore, only have 45 reputation. As such, I could not simply add a comment to the above existing post and had to create a whole new post even though they are the same issue....seems silly. But I digress....

I wanted to provide additional comments in the hopes to get an answer. My issue started suddenly the a few days ago. I made no major changes to references, VS updates, etc... However, when I right click my csproj in visual studio, I get the error and I have to click it five times before it goes away, at which point I finally get the menu.

Again, I have made no major changes BUT I went ahead and confirmed that:

1. My target version and Min version is Windows 10(10.0; Build 10586). That is the SDK version that I have installed and am using.
2. I verified that my NuGet updates are complete and that my Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform are installed and update to date (5.2.2 as of now).
3. I do have a reference also to "Universal Windows". This was created automatically when I created my project and I cannot remove this reference but it is there. When I select it, I do see that it is "UAP,Version=10.0.10586.0" so this should be good. I do notice a possible issue here. Again, this reference was created for me and I cannot remove or change it. However, it is pointed to a folder named

> C:\Program Files(x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsVoipContract\1.0.0.0\

Why did the Windows Universal reference default to that folder and only that folder? I am not using VoIP so I wonder why it chose this one? Also, what if I need some of the other references in the References folder?

4. I created a brand new Windows Universal project and the same error happens on a fresh project.

Please help, it is annoying. Project still seems to build and work fine though.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried checking the logs during startup? See example
http://blog.masterdevs.com/debugging-a-visual-studio-crash/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue in my case, it was an extension that I added on to Visual Studio provided by SyncFusion (which their installer actually creates 7 or se extensions in Visual Studio). After troubleshooting my issue and doing some of the same things to resolve (repairing .Net, SDK, Visual Studio) I then thought about the error a bit more. While it is cryptic (and has poor english "An Exception has been occured") these are all clues that it could be any of the frameworks that I have installed via extensions as well.

I also had another clue, the issue started happening a few weeks ago, around the time I updated my SyncFusion controls to the latest version.

So, I went to Tools > Extensions and Updates. I went to Installed > All and found all of the SyncFusion items (there are several) and disabled them all. After I disabled them, and restarted Visual Studio, the problem went away!!!

This is a workaround for now. In the meantime, I put in a support ticket with SyncFusion on the issue. I will certainly update this thread when I get a response from them. Also in the meantime, I then went back and re-enabled each of them again, one at a time, to see who the real culprit was. In my case it was the SyncFusion Web Conversion and Migration extension.

If any of you are not using SyncFusion but having odd Visual Studio issues such as this, I suggest doing something similar by going through your extensions and disable any that you added on, starting with the most recent add ons, especially if they were added around the same time you started having the problem until you find the culprit.

Hope this helps!